# How to include compiled CSS/JS with hashed file name into the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, css, compilation, webpack

If you compile/merge the CSS/JS files into one with a compiler (e.g. webpack, grunt),
the name of the file is hashed (e.g. df48gf8d789ds9fs.css).

Is there some kind of convention of including these files into the website?

I mean, as per usual, you would do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

However, if I have a hashed file name, I can not hard-code it like above.

How shall one do it e.g. in PHP?

My idea is like so, but I just do not know, there has to be a better solution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_dir_files_and_find_one_css(); ?>" />
```

**EDIT:**
Yes, I would like to have hashed file name, to prevent a browser from caching the file.

Comment: People combine css and JS into a single file?  Sorry can't help, that just seems so odd to me... though I assume there is a use-case I'm unaware of.

Comment: If you are compiling it you can add the output file name. And no, you have to add it manually or add a task to add those files into your html.

Comment: +Andrew Coder Code is combined or minified is done to optimize delivery times of the HTTP requests made by the browser - faster page loading.

Comment: Giving a filename you prevent having differents filenames everytime you compile.

Comment: Yes, I speciffically would like to have hashed file name to prevent a browsers from caching obsolette styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the hash is used for updating old caches that the browser may have and a way to use the file could be to just inject the filename into the HTML when building your project through a script of some sorts. However, specifying a filename when using the compiler doesn't cause this problem.